# Read file android

Tags: android, filepath, android-file

I've created a data.txt using this code :

```
String data = "etc etc etc etc。。" 
                   try {
                   FileOutputStream fOut;

                   fOut = openFileOutput("data.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

                   OutputStreamWriter fw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 

                   fw.write(data);
                   fw.flush();
                   fw.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
```

but how do I know where it was wrote into? How do I define a path for my data.txt?

I want to read it using other activity, so I need to know how to read from path as well..

Comment: This is standard Java File IO. Google can point you to a thousand tutorials

Comment: I tried whole day, it doesn't work!!

Comment: You should be using [`Environment.getDataDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) and creating a file there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way...

```
     static final String FILE_LOG = "log.txt";

    String s = "Hello";
            File file;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;

            try
            {
                file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), FILE_LOG);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                fos.write(s.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

   String path = file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
   Toast.makeText(this, "File is saved to " + path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   Log.e("PATH", path);
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks...

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String data = "etc etc etc etc。。";
try{
    if (root.canWrite()){
        File txtfile = new File(root, "data.txt");
        FileWriter txtwriter = new FileWriter(txtfile, true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(txtwriter);
        out.write(data);
        out.close();
    }
}
catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

This code will create a data.txt file into your external storage root directory. Don't forget to add this permisson to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```